# Multivariate Newton-Raphson in R language (equations that contains integral)

Tags: computer-science, regression, newton-raphson

I am trying to apply multivariate Newton-Raphson method using R language. However I have encountered some difficulties to define functions which includes the integral in the equations. For instance, the general form of the equations look like below.
\begin{align}
F_{a}(a,b) = \int_{\text{all}}f(z;a,b)dz - a &= 0, \\
F_{b}(a,b) = \int_{\text{all}}g(z;a,b)dz - b &= 0.
\end{align}
The R code that I applied is written on the bottom.

```
integrand_f <- function(z) { some function f(z;a,b) }
integrand_g <- function(z) { some function g(z;a,b) }

F_a <- function(a,b) { integrate(integrand_f,-Inf,Inf)$value - a }
F_b <- function(a,b) { integrate(integrand_g,-Inf,Inf)$value - b }
```

Apparently, when I substitute initial values $(a_{0},b_{0})$ in both $F_{a}$ and $F_{b}$, the output that I get is $-a_{0}$ and $-b_{0}$, respectively. In other words, the integral parts of both functions do not give a meaningful output but zero. How should I fix this problem?

**NEW ATTEMPT**

Apparently, if I apply `Vectorize` function:

```
F_a <- Vectorize(function(a,b) { integrate(integrand_f,-Inf,Inf)$value - a })
```

I get some non-trivial value. Perhaps could this be a correct way to compute?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the actual Newton-Raphson step? Maybe there's a bug in that.

Comment: I haven't written the actual Newton-Raphson script yet. But I just substitute some numbers in the functions whether it correctly works or not.

Comment: Is it possible the arguments `a` and `b` of `F_a` and `F_b` aren't being successfully passed to `integrand_f` and `integrand_g`, or that the integration isn't over `x`? Try including some print statements inside their functions to see what's passed to what, and what comes out of it.

Comment: One more question. Do you want to simultaneously solve $F_a=F_b=0$, i.e. use [a $2$-dimensional Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#k_variables,_k_functions)?

Comment: @J.G. Yes. I am trying to solve it simultaneously. I am still thinking about how should I write the script, but I hope I can solve the problem successfully before the end of today : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pp.13-16 [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf) discuss a library function that does what you need to use Newton-Raphson, the [`multiroot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rootSolve/versions/1.8.2/topics/multiroot) function in the [`rootSolve`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rootSolve/versions/1.8.2) package. The compulsory arguments of `multiroot` are a function `f`, which for your purposes will send a 2D vector to a 2D vector, and an initial value for its argument so you can begin the iteration. The real challenge is creating the function `f`, whose first and second components should be the values of `F_a` and `F_b`. So you want something like:

```
F_a <- function(a, b) integrate(function(z) some_function_f(a, b), -Inf, Inf)$value-a

F_b <- function(a, b) integrate(function(z) some_function_g(a, b), -Inf, Inf)$value-b

f <- function(v)
{
    a <- v[1]
    b <- v[2]
    c(F_a(a, b), F_b(a, b))
}

solve_for_a_and_b <- function(original_a, original_b) rootSolve::multiroot(f, c(original_a, original_b))
```